# Sonar cloud new code only supports master/default branch

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarlint

Currently, we have already implemented the SonarQube on Azure VM, Due to cost and maintenance activity, we are thinking about moving to SonarCloud. Basic differences we are having from the pricing point of view and LOC, by feature-wise, am looking for major differences

Question: We have observed that in SonarQube we can set new code analysis on any branch whereas I did not find the same thing in SonarCloud it only allows me to set new code only on the Master/Default branch, the rest of the branches are not having options to set, also If I set the previous version, specific analysis the build fails for other branches except for master/default.

How can we set a new code rule for branches?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

For SonarCloud, the prime focus is on the **developer’s workflow** and bringing value to the development team within their existing ALM environment. Thus, **the ‘Enterprise’ use-case is not currently addressed by SonarCloud.**

SonarCloud is hosted by SonarSource in AWS and your code will be stored in a private subnet which is secured but again it's your choice..!! (We prefer to keep our code in our own infra)

**For Enterprise use-cases, explore SonarQube**

SonarQube Enterprise Edition (EE) includes a few management features that may be valuable to your organization. SonarQube along with a supported database is installed on your own on-site servers or in a self-managed cloud environment

SonarQube is enterprise ready application with all the required configurations whereas SonarCloud is missing enterprise level functions such as Authentication, Portfolios, Global settings, Branch & New code, and Housekeeping etc. that is why you are unable to set New code analysis on branch level.
SonarCloud meant for small projects that focuses on Master where your application will be built and deployed using only Master/release branch and rest of the branches are considered as a short-living branches in which we don't get much more options to play.

As part of Licensing and services both products cover essentially the same languages (SonarCloud doesn’t support PL/I, RPG or VB6) and support similar functions, SonarCloud additionally offers a SonarServer and Database to store the code and results with all the services like database and server SonarCloud still much more cheaper than the SonarQube but why?  --

You can go through the below links for more details.

https://blog.sonarsource.com/sq-sc_guidance

https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/user-guide/new-code/